# I want to replace 'ld' with 'gcc' in my Makefile to link my kernel objects

Tags: gcc, makefile, ld, gcov, opensolaris

In my project I have makefiles which build Solaris kernel modules, and they use `gcc` to compile files but use `ld` to link all `.o` files together into a kernel module. I am trying to include some coverage options like gcov (`-fprofile-arcs`) or tcov (`-xprofile=tcov`) in my build, hence I want to replace `ld` with `gcc` during linking also.

But as soon as I use replace `gcc` with `ld`, the builds start failing with lot of "undefined symbol" errors, even if I use some compile flags and get rid of these errors, the kernel module will not load into my Solaris kernel at all.

For example:

```
$ /usr/ccs/bin/ld -r -dy -Nstrmod/rpcmod -Nfs/nfs \
                  -Nmisc/rpcsec -Nmisc/klmmod -Nfs/zfs \
                  -o debug64/nfssrv \
                  debug64/nfs_server.o debug64/nfs_srv.o debug64/nfs3_srv.o \
                  debug64/nfs_acl_srv.o debug64/nfs_auth.o obj64/nfs41_srv.o \
                  obj64/ctl_ds_srv.o obj64/dserv_server.o
```

`ld` works fine but with `gcc` I get following errors:

```
/opt/gcc-4.4.4/bin/gcc -m64 -z muldefs \
                       -Lmod/rpcmod -Lfs/nfs -Lmisc/rpcsec \
                       -Lmisc/klmmod -Lfs/zfs \
                       -o obj64/nfssrv \
                       obj64/nfs_server.o obj64/nfs_srv.o obj64/nfs3_srv.o
                       obj64/nfs_acl_srv.o obj64/nfs_auth.o obj64/nfs41_srv.o 
                       obj64/ctl_ds_srv.o obj64/dserv_server.o

Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
hz                                  obj64/nfs_server.o
p0                                  obj64/nfs_server.o
nfs_range_set                       obj64/nfs41_srv.o
getf                                obj64/nfs_server.o
log2                                obj64/nfs4_state.o
main                                /usr/lib/amd64/crt1.o
stoi                                obj64/ctl_ds_srv.o
dmu_object_alloc                    obj64/dserv_server.o
nvpair_name                         obj64/nfs4_srv.o
__dtrace_probe_nfss41__i__destroy_encap_session obj64/nfs41_srv.o
__dtrace_probe_nfssrv__i__dscp_freeing_device_entries obj64/ctl_ds_srv.o
mod_install                         obj64/nfs_server.o
xdr_faststatfs                      obj64/nfs_server.o
xdr_WRITE3res                       obj64/nfs_server.o
svc_pool_control                    obj64/nfs_server.o
```

Comment: `gcc` would still in the end call the same `ld`. I do not have all the details of your setup, but I presume if direct invocation of `ld` yields you the desired result, you should probably tell `gcc` to pass corresponding flags to it (`-Wl,<LDFLAG>`). In particular the `-N` ones for direct linking entries might be of relevance?

Answer (score 2):

Warning the option -L allows to specify a path where to search for libraries, to specify a library you want to link with you (also) have to use the option -l

So a priori you have to add the options `-lrpcmod -lnfs -lrpcsec -lklmmod -lzfs`

More details in [GCC Linking Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500766/gcc-linking-options)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the GNU linker called through the `gcc` compiler driver will try to create a standard executable. Consequently, if you don't tell it otherwise, `ld` will use its default linker script, the C startup code and it will look for a `main()` routine and everything else that makes a valid executable.

I'm not too familiar with Solaris, but would bet this will not be suitable to build kernel modules. I would expect kernel modules will at least require some options like `-ffreestanding`, `-nostdlibs` and most likely a non-default linker script that's probably very different from the default one used for applications.

Even if you manage to link your kernel modules this way, I seriously doubt you will be finished. The `gcov` instrumentation routines most likely do not expect to live within a kernel driver but expect a proper C execution environment (e.g. it will at least expect to `fopen()` a file to `fwrite()` its findings). A kernel driver, however, does not have this comfort. You'll probably find yourself confronted with the problem to get the `gcov` data somehow out of your kernel modules.

Not saying this is not doable, but it certainly will be a lot of work.